# Blocking Facebook Android app from router?

Tags: router, blocking, facebook

What are the domain names that I should block to stop accessing users to the Facebook applications through android phones with my router?

Comment: See [https://github.com/jmdugan/blocklists/blob/master/corporations/facebook/all](https://github.com/jmdugan/blocklists/blob/master/corporations/facebook/all). But keep in mind, this also block web version.

Comment: @Lluser I want to block Facebook accessing using android application

Comment: That depends on how sophisticated is your router, if it can block sites conditional on the MAC address of the phones (or block all but whitelist the computers).

Comment: @NiroshanRatnayake Do you want this filter for specific device (yours), or globally for any Android device connected to your network? Because if you want to prevent FB app in your Android device from network access on your wifi (or any other) is better to solve it right on the device. For example [Net Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard)